# Selenium crashed on M1 mac: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Selenium doen't seems to start properly,
Keep raising **selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: **
Would someone knows how to fix it?

about my setting info

```
Mac M1 pro
Chrome version: 107.0.5304.87
ChromeDriver: 107.0.5304.62
selenium version: 4.5.0
```

First I tried the webdriver manual downloaded.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service


s = Service('/Users/itsmeleah/code/itsmeleahh/Get-Taobao-Data/chromedriver')
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

the log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/itsmeleah/code/itsmeleahh/Get-Taobao-Data/scraping_test.py", line 11, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chrome_options)
  File "/Users/itsmeleah/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    super().__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/Users/itsmeleah/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/Users/itsmeleah/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 272, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Users/itsmeleah/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 364, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/Users/itsmeleah/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 429, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/itsmeleah/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 207, in check_response
    raise exception_class(value)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message:
```

Sencondly, I used the chromedrive manager, still got the same error

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

```
[WDM] - Downloading: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 8.41M/8.41M [00:25<00:00, 348kB/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/itsmeleah/code/itsmeleahh/Get-Taobao-Data/scraping_test.py", line 19, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
  File "/Users/itsmeleah/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    super().__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/Users/itsmeleah/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/Users/itsmeleah/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 272, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Users/itsmeleah/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 364, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/Users/itsmeleah/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 429, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/itsmeleah/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 207, in check_response
    raise exception_class(value)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message:
```

There's no window popping out after executing the code, and I also tried to close my existing chrome windows to avoid the conflicts, but still not working.

Comment: hard to say without seeing the exception.  Did you leave that out or does it just say "Message: "?  To troubleshoot remove chromeoptions... just use default chromedriver to see if it helps.  (and make sure you are using the m1/arm version of chromedriver)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the chrome browser installed.

`brew install google-chrome`

Make sure to run the newest versions of selenium and webdriver_manager.

`python3 -m pip install --upgrade selenium webdriver_manager`

Delete all existing downloads with `rm -rf ~/.wdm` and try again. Make sure to not run your script as root.